# Airflow Dag never runs as per the schedule on Google Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

Below is my default params along with the start date and schedule interval followed by the dag definitions. If triggered manually, everything works fine. But none of my Dag scripts run as per the scheduled timing.

```
    default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2019,8,31),
    'email_on_failure':True,
    'retries':1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'depends_on_past':False,
    'email':['sid-test@gmail.com'],
    'schedule_interval':'0 */2 * * *' # Every 2 Hours
}

    dag = DAG('mktg_cost_dag',default_args=default_args,catchup=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the schedule interval from the default args. It looks that when using it inside the the default args, it is not detected properly by Airflow:

```
 default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'start_date': datetime(2019,8,31),
'email_on_failure':True,
'retries':1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
'depends_on_past':False,
'email':['sid-test@gmail.com']
}

dag = DAG('mktg_cost_dag',default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 */2 * * *', catchup=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`schedule_interval` is a DAG property, so you should remove it from `default_args` and set it inside `DAG()`.

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2019,8,31),
    'email_on_failure':True,
    'retries':1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'depends_on_past':False,
    'email':['sid-test@gmail.com'],
}

dag = DAG('mktg_cost_dag',default_args=default_args,catchup=False, schedule_interval='0 */2 * * *')
```